# couldnt get right result in php

Tags: php, mysql, html

when I write in php file: 
`echo $myrow["persons_id"]` it gives right answer: 125.

but I want to get result like this: `your ID is:125`

when I write:

```
echo "your ID is:" . $myrow['Persons_id']
```

I get text: `your ID is:` without ID number).
what is wrong?

Comment: `$myrow['Persons_id']` and `$myrow["persons_id"]` are two different variables. Array keys are case sensitive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php associative array and switch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832506/php-associative-array-and-switch)

Answer (score 1):

You're capitalizing the P

```
echo "your ID is:" . $myrow['persons_id']
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the examples you wrote are with the P capitalized on purpose I will ignore that and assume that on your end you are writting it corrrectly.

you can easily get the array value by doing

```
echo "your ID is: {$myrow['persons_id']}.";
```

The `{}` inside the string help php know that what it is between them will be code and not plain text.

Comment: It works. really the reason was in capitalizing P. thanks Squeegy, ddrjm.

Comment: Have you help me resolve another problem: submit input is on the main page. when I press submit button, I get  answer on the new, blank page:"Your ID is ...". What to add on php code to get this text on the main page?   in index.php I write: <form action="select_res.php?type=<?php echo $_GET[type]?>" method="post">  (will continue in next comment)

Comment: and in select_res.php I write:
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("lottery", $db);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT persons_id FROM persons WHERE 'FirstName'='".$_POST['FirstName']."'");
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $myrow['persons_id'];
echo "Your ID:", $myrow['Persons_id']; 
?>

Comment: The way I see it you can do that via an javascript ajax request handled by the form and the result will go into an element inside your page, or you can, inside your select_res.php write to a global variable with the string you want to show, and redirect back to the index page and check if that global variable is set, if so you can simply echo it out from there.